# Add custom link to openlayer maps Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

Hello can some one tell me how to add a custom link to openlayer maps marker? I want to be able to open a hidden div when i press the marker. I am trying to do something like this http://www.porcelanosa.com/showroom-locator however i can only add simple information via the pop up feature of the marker via text file. Right now i am using the WP plugin (OpenStreetMap Plugin V2.4.1). I tried multiple examples however none of them shows how to add a custom link to the marker

Comment: Every `<div>` containing a marker-`<img>` has an id-property. Example: `<div id="OL_Icon_1829">`...image-tag...`</div>`. Can't you use it to attach an event listener?

Comment: I will try, can you show me an example ? i will check the net too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can register a listener on your marker. 
A full example can be found here: [Markers Layer Example](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/markers.html).

```
marker.events.register('mousedown', marker, 
    function(evt) { 
        alert(this.icon.url); OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt); 
    }
);
```

if you are using a vector layer, you could register a feature selection event on it:

```
var myLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(locale.layerStationMarkers, {
    eventListeners: {
        "featureselected": onFeatureSelectMethod(),
        "featureunselected": onStationFeatureUnselect()
    }
});
```